# Authorship, and order of authors

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-writing

Currently I am writing a paper with several collaborators; although I am the primary author to this (I have done a large (>85%) majority of the work and have actually written the paper) my last name begins with W. I feel obligated to include their names on the paper, however, I fear that doing so will degrade my ownership of the paper. Where should I mention them in the paper?

Comment: This kind of questions is usually more welcome and on-topic on academia.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @federico I would agree except that every academic field other than maths uses non-alphabetic author order to signal something about roles or relative contributions.

Comment: The AMS has guidelines concerning whom should be offered authorship on a paper:  "However, the authors listed for a paper must all have made a significant contribution to its content, and all who have made such a contribution must be offered the opportunity to be listed as an author."  See http://www.ams.org/notices/200206/from-ams-sec.pdf

Comment: don't use the name nicbit on the manuscript

Comment: Make sure you ask the other collaborators what they want, and err on the generous side in assigning credit and offering co-authorship.

Comment: Put first name "Mother Nature" and then all in alphatical order, since anyway all the knowledge is collective and we only discover what is going on. Also put in acknowledgements thanks to all teachers and uni professors and all authors of the papers you read, otherwise you would know nothing in Maths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are co-authors on the paper then add them alphabetically as is customary for math journals.  Otherwise if they are not co-authors then just mention them in acknowledgements.  If you want to record the author contributions, you can add this as a separate section after acknowledgements.  You can also list yourself as the "corresponding author" if you want to show that you have more ownership of the paper.

Edit: Although I don't disagree with most of the other answer, I think that the role of corresponding author will often be interpreted as having more significance than simply as the co-author with the most stable email address.  As in one of the comments on the question [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10062/does-corresponding-author-carry-an-implied-meaning) I've shared the experience of being co-author on a paper where the PI was suspiciously eager to be corresponding author.  I'm not sure how widespread is the interpretation like 'corresponding authorship signals primary authorship when the author order is alphabetical and there is no other indication' but I think it's good to at least be aware that some people will interpret it in this way.

Answer (score 13):

I completely disagree with "guest"s answer. It is quite possible to have authors in non-alphabetical order, and "corresponding author" means that that person has a steady mailing address (often some of the authors are postodcs). In mathematics it is customary to have authors in alphabetical order, it's true, so having a non-alphabetical order underscores that there is major inequality in contribution (needless to say, all authors must agree to this).

Comment: This is what I hear from senior mathematicians in my field (combinatorics). I wonder if things are slightly different between fields of math, regions (e.g., West vs. Asia), generations, etc. If mathematics had a universal culture about the order of authors with no exception, Inventiones wouldn't have had to publish a corrigendum like this one...: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01232247 (To give credit where credit is due, I found this example in this MO answer http://mathoverflow.net/a/20085/27829)

Comment: @YuichiroFujiwara that corrigendum has an interesting history, but what's amusing (not to me at the time, nor now, but perhaps to some) is that the page proofs had the correct order of authors, and then _the typesetter_ decided that (s)he had never seen alphabetic inversion, and changed things without informing anyone. So, apparently guest's view was popular in typesetting circles.

Comment: "It is quite possible to have authors in non-alphabetical order."  That's quite true, and the proof is that it happens every now and again.  However, because unalphabetical orderings occur in less than 1% of math papers, it does not seem to be a good idea to use this practice to convey a message about author contributions.  When I see an unalphabetized paper I can tell that the authors are trying to signify something, but because I am unfamiliar with the practice, I never know exactly what.

Comment: Moreover, since it occurs so rarely even when in practice lots of math papers have unequal contributions, when I do see it I wonder whether the junior authors are being bullied by the senior authors.  I think a much better practice would be to "record author contributions" as in the other answer.  Admittedly this is not done often either, but I'm not sure why.  I did this in an important (by my standards) paper that I wrote with a somewhat junior coauthor: some of the results came from his thesis (which I had nothing to do with), and I wanted that to be part of the record.

Comment: One final point: if you want to convey information about contributions based on ordering of names, what do you do if the person whose contribution you wish to emphasize comes first in the alphabet?

Comment: @IgorRivin Ah, I'm sorry if my careless comment came out sounding sarcastic by bringing up that particular example about your paper; I should've checked who wrote the answer before posting the comment... Also, thank you for the interesting tidbit!

Comment: @PeteL.Clark The problem with describing who did what (which _is_ done occasionally) is that no one reads those things. Your last comment is certainly valid, and it is a difficult situation, at least for papers (for books one has some options). However, the current system, where, as a consequence, if two authors have an Annals paper, then they BOTH (or all five) get "full credit" for promotion, etc, is completely corrupt and stupid.

Comment: (BY the way, I didn't track the link until now.  I certainly agree that the decision about how to order the authors names belongs with the authors and not the typesetter.  One would have every right to be displeased about the incident mentioned.)

Comment: @YuichiroFujiwara not at all, I did not take it as sarcastic at all (and of course, my experience with that paper made me more likely to write the answer I did).

Comment: @Igor: "no one reads those things".  I do.  Unfortunately I largely agree with you that our profession is not very interested in looking inside the black box of joint work (and, though I might not state it as strongly as you have, I do find this practice problematic).  But the suspicion that the information provided might be ignored does not seem to be a good reason not to provide the information.

Comment: In contrast, say that *Inventiones* publishes a paper by Rivin and Clark.  (May it come to pass...)  I can see that this means Clark did less than half the work, but how much less?  Thirty percent?  Ten percent?  The minimum amount necessary for Clark's name to be included according to AMS ethical standards?  How much is that??

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I certainly agree that one should provide the information, but if in joint work by Alpher and Bethe, Bethe figured out how to prove the GRH, but he needed the value of some L-function at $\sqrt{17},$ which was mildly tricky, and done by Alpher (though could have been done by any number of other people), should GRH be now renamed the Alpher-Bethe theorem? You know it would, the way things are now.

Comment: @IgorRivin Thank you for your kind reply. I apologize for bringing up the unpleasant experience in a comment when the post was by none other than the paper's co-author. It was inappropriate.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark in fact, the well-known LLL algorithm is attributed (in the paper) to Lovasz (the rest of the paper is an application to factoring, which, while cool, is much less significant than the Lovasz algorithm), but no one cares.

Comment: @Igor: As you can see, I agree with you on your complaint; I just think that your proposed remedy is probably unnecessary and certainly insufficient.  With regard to your last comment: you do realize it is self-defeating, right? :)  Nevertheless your points are well-taken.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark It is only somewhat self-defeating, since I am the only person I know who cares. A better example: in that Rivin-Hodgson paper, it states very clearly that the results contained therein are those of Rivin's PhD thesis. Nevertheless, the main result is usually referred to as the Hodgson-Rivin theorem (nobody reads corrigenda either; I should have made Inventiones reprint the paper, but I was just returning to mathematics at the time, and did not have the confidence).

Comment: "A better example: in that Rivin-Hodgson paper, it states very clearly that the results contained therein are those of Rivin's PhD thesis."  Ah, I see.  As I said, "One would have every right to be displeased..."

Comment: @PeteL.Clark this is tangential, but when I had a conversation with the editor [a famous french geometer] (on the phone) about this, he recounted the tale of how Siegel was brought in to arbitrate between Selberg and Erdos, and told these two young punks that "in a hundred years no one will care". I suspect they were about as convinced by that argument as I was.

Comment: Another thing to note about author order is that it is not all other fields that has the last author be the one who did the least. Sometimes in the biomedical sciences, the last author is the one who had the overall responsibility for the project.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, in the hard sciences there is a somewhat complicated scheme, where the first and the last authors are more important than the middle, but papers still get cited as "Zorba et al"

Comment: This situation arises frequently when doing interdisciplinary research.  I'm early in my career, and I've decided to be a bit more aggressive when I do 85% of the work by asking that I be first author. I don't know who on a hiring committee will read my CV, but often it will not be a mathematician.